# new Imagick() is not accepting certain array

Tags: php, arrays, imagick

I am trying to create a new instance of Imagick:

```
  $original = new Imagick($array);
```

I do this in two different instances. One way always works, and the other way always fails, but they use the same exact array (the array isn't always identical, but for ease of explanation, I am showing an example that happens to use identical arrays). Here is a `var_dump` of each array:

Working Array:

```
  array(3) { [0]=> string(20) "image_files/bbb0.jpg" [1]=> string(20) "image_files/bbb1.jpg" [2]=> string(20) "image_files/bbb2.jpg" }
```

Failing Array:

```
  array(3) { [0]=> string(20) "image_files/bbb0.jpg" [1]=> string(20) "image_files/bbb1.jpg" [2]=> string(20) "image_files/bbb2.jpg" }
```

As you can see, they are identical, so why is my PHP dying at

```
$new = new Imagick($array);
```

Is there something different about the second array that I'm not seeing?

EDIT: Here's the code that constructs the array that is failing:

```
$n = $_GET["n"];
$city = preg_replace("/[0-9]/", "", $n);
$num = preg_replace("/".$city."/","",$n);

// create an array to hold directory list
$results = array();
// create a handler for the directory
$directory = '../image_files';
$handler = opendir($directory);

while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
// if file isn't this directory or its parent, add it to the results
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
    // check with regex that the file format is what we're expecting and not something else
    if (preg_match("/^".$city."[1-9][0-9]\.jpg$/i",$file)) {
    if (preg_match("/^".$city.$num."\.jpg$/i",$file)) { 
        unlink("../image_files/".$file);
    } else {
        $results[] = "../image_files/" . $file;
    }
    } else if (preg_match("/^".$city."[0-9]\.jpg$/i",$file)) {
    if (preg_match("/^".$city.$num."\.jpg$/i",$file)) { 
        unlink("../image_files/".$file);
    } else {
        $results[] = "../image_files/" . $file;
    }
    } 
    }
}

sort($results);

$i = 0;
$newResults = array();
foreach( $results as $key => $value ) {
$old = $value;
//echo "old: " . $old . " ";
if (preg_match("/[1-9][0-9]/",$value)) {
    $newstr = preg_replace("/[1-9][0-9]/", $i."temp", $value);
} else if (preg_match("/[0-9]/",$value)) {
    $newstr = preg_replace("/[0-9]/", $i."temp", $value);
}

$newResults[] = $newstr;
//echo "new: " . $newstr . "<br>";
rename($old,$newstr);
    $i++;
}

// create an array to hold directory list
$results = array();
// create a handler for the directory
$directory = '../image_files';
$handler = opendir($directory);

while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
// if file isn't this directory or its parent, add it to the results
if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
    $old = $file;
    $new = preg_replace("/temp/", "", $file);
        rename("../image_files/".$old,"../image_files/".$new);
    }
}

$finalResults = array();

foreach( $newResults as $key => $value ) {
    $newstr = str_replace("../", "", $value);
    $newstr = str_replace("temp","",$newstr);
    $finalResults[] = $newstr; 
}

sort($finalResults);

createMontage($finalResults,"-a",$city);
```

Comment: The arrays are identical. No special hidden chars, nothing.

Comment: Yes they are, this is why I am going crazy over this.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more context, it's obviously not the array that's at fault.

Comment: Do you get any exceptions? Are the scripts calling this in the same directory? Do you do any `chdir` or anything before calling the second time?

Comment: Is it possible, that the 1st is an actual array and the second one is a string containing the output of an array?

Comment: @hank I'm not sure how to check for an exception. Yes, the scripts are in the same directory. I do an `unlink`, `preg_replace`, and `rename`'s before the second array is created.

Comment: @DainisAbols No, both are actual arrays.

Comment: Did you do `print_r($array)` just before `$new = new Imagick($array);` ?

Comment: @DainisAbols No, I did `var_dump` just before `$new = new Imagick($array)`. The result of the `var_dumps` is what you see above as "Working Array" and "Failing Array"

Comment: Can you verify that the files actually do exist the second time around, use `file_exists` on every item in the array.

Comment: @hank That's is, the files don't exist. Is this maybe due to a delay in `rename`?

Comment: @hank FYI, I ran `file_exists` for both arrays. The working arrays returned all files exist, but the non-working returned every file did not exist even though the array items are identical. This baffles me.

Comment: So, there is your problem, the files does not exist. Where do you run `rename` - the problem is probably there, you are not renaming them properly or something.

Comment: @hank I've found the problem, it was a `dir` problem like you suggested before. Although this 2nd file is in the same directory as the 1st file, the 1st script is executed from 1 dir up while the 2nd is loaded directly. Thanks Hank!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the directory structure of the PHP files.

The "working array" is being created from the base directory.
The "failing array" is being created from a directory named `actions`.

It doesn't matter where the script you're running exists, it matters what loaded that script (ie. Was it loaded from the root dir via `include` or `require`? Or was is called directly `www.example.com/scripts/script.php`). This will determine how to construct your path to other files.

Comment: Use `dirname(__FILE__) . '/some/path/file.ext'` and you will always start from the current file directory. Doesn't matter if the file itself is included or ran directly.